# Combinatorics Question: Graph Algorithms

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

If a weighted graph is disconnected, it has no spanning trees. (obviously)
However, is there a way to find a spanning forest of minimum weight in the disconnected graphs???

If anyone could, I am confused on how to use Kruskal’s and Prim’s algorithm to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Find the minimum spanning tree of each component?

Answer (score 2):

As was suggested in the comments, just find a minimal weight spanning tree in each component separately; you cannot do better than this. Either Kruskal’s or Prim’s algorithm will serve to find these spanning trees.

Comment: Perhaps a brief note about finding the components is worth adding?

Comment: @hardmath: I don’t really know what one would say, since it depends so much on how the graph is represented.